# Is there a (signed) measure on a compact manifold that assigns zero mass to the boundary of each open set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $M$ be a finite dimensional compact manifold without boundary. Is there a signed Borel measure $\mu$ so that any nowhere dense set has $\mu$ measure zero?

I think the answer is no in general, but if so, are there are any spaces on which it would hold?

Thanks in advance for any references or answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No nonzero such $\mu$ can exist if $M$ has positive dimension.  Indeed, suppose you have such a $\mu$, let $V\subseteq M$ be any open set and let $\{q_n\}\subseteq V$ be a countable dense subset.  Since $M$ has positive dimension, for each $n$ the singleton $\{q_n\}$ is nowhere dense and so $\mu(\{q_n\})=0$.  For any $\epsilon>0$, you can then choose a small open neighborhood $U_n\subseteq V$ of $q_n$ such that $|\mu|(U_n)<\epsilon/2^n$.  Taking $U=\bigcup U_n$, the set $U$ is open and dense in $V$ but $|\mu|(U)<\epsilon$.  Now $V\setminus U$ is nowhere dense, so $\mu(V\setminus U)=0$.  It follows that $|\mu(V)|=|\mu(U)|<\epsilon$.  Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this means $\mu(V)=0$.  Since $V\subseteq M$ was an arbitrary open set, this implies $\mu=0$.